# Getting console error after upgrading the ng2-pdf-viewer to latest version 10.0.0

Tags: angular, pdf, console, pdfjs-dist, ng2-pdf-viewer

After upgrading to the latest version (10.0.0) of ng2-pdf-viewer, I am receiving a console error: '**no resource to load, early way out.**' However, this error does not seem to affect functionality at the moment. What could be the reason for this error, and how can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: showing your code will help people determine where the error might be coming from.